# tinymce: how to edit php pages without stripping php?

Tags: tinymce

I need to give my client the ability to change his pages through tinyMCE.
Trouble is these pages contain some php script and tineyMCE strips the php script : infact it adds some HTML comment to disable it.

How can I pass through ?

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TinyMCE is *not* a text editor: it is more akin to a word processor. You could (perhaps) technically use the "HTML source editor" (the [button labeled HTML in this example](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php)) but I don't think that would be a pleasant experience and it might not even work at all.

If you're looking for a code editor, may I suggest [Ace](http://ace.ajax.org/)? It is a code editor and seems suited to what your needs are.